# Можно ли писать в контексте метапрограммирования на Ассемблере?

Tags: ассемблер, метапрограммирование

Встретил в интернете утверждение, что писать в контексте метапрограммирования. Можно на любом языке, в том числе и на асме. Гугл по этому делу ничего не знает ... ну кроме, Lisp-а и C++, с Python. А как с этим в других языках вообще хз, но жутко интересно

Comment: Ассемблер - это и есть машинный код. Его и генерируют другие ЯП.

Comment: Если под метапрограммированием вы подразумеваете генерацию кода (или его самомодификацию) во время выполнения, то безусловно, да. Если изменения во время компиляции, то в тех рамках, которые предоставляет текстовый препроцессор, которым вы обрабатываете исходный текст программы на асме